# SVG Hover State with Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm defining an SVG on my page with the following `defs`.

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <g id="stroke-hexagon">
            <polygon fill="#002663" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="12" points="57.8,185 5.8,95 57.8,5 161.8,5 213.8,95 161.8,185 "/>

        </g>

        <g id="hexagon">
            <polygon fill="#006890" points="52,180 0,90 52,0 156,0 208,90 156,180 "/>
        </g>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

...and implementing it later in the HTML using this:

```
<svg width="208px" height="180px" viewBox="0 0 208 180" >
    <use xlink:href="#hexagon"></use>
    <text class="faicon" x="50%" y="70px" fill="white" font-size="80px" text-anchor="middle">&#xf040</text>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="70%" fill="white">Logo Here</text>
</svg>
```

Works totally fine. I am also able to style the `polygon`'s fill with simple CSS. Looks like this:

```
#hexagon:hover polygon {
    fill:#990000;
}
```

The hover effect fails, however, whenever the mouse leaves the `polygon` and instead hovers over either of the 'text' elements within the `svg`. Is there a way to define a CSS rule that prevents this behavior. Or, would it be better (easier) to change the attribute using JS / jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your texts are rendered on top of your polygon and are therefore intercepting mouse events. You should set up a css rule like

```
text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent the text from becoming a target of mouse events which should give you the desired hover effect for the polygon.